# Recursively construct a tree without using a `return` statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I would like to inquire about the scope in Python of an object that is a class variable.

```
import numpy as np


class treeNode:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None
        self.value = key


def insert(root,key):
    if root is None:
        return treeNode(key)
    else:
        if root.value == key:
            return root
        elif root.value<key:
            root.rightChild = insert(root.rightChild,key)
        else:
            root.leftChild = insert(root.leftChild,key)
    return root

def insert_1(root,key):
    if root is None:
        root = treeNode(key)
    else:
        if root.value<key:
            insert_1(root.rightChild,key)
        elif root.value>key:
            insert_1(root.leftChild,key)

def construct_tree(a):
    def insert_1(root,key):
        if root is None:
            root = treeNode(key)
        else:
            if root.value<key:
                insert_1(root.rightChild,key)
            elif root.value>key:
                insert_1(root.leftChild,key)

    root = treeNode(a[0])
    for k in a:
        insert_1(root,k)

    return root

if __name__ == '__main__':

    np.random.seed(1)
    a = np.random.rand(12)

    tree = treeNode(a[0])
    for k in a:
        insert(tree,k)

    for k in a:
        insert_1(tree,k)


    tree_1 = construct_tree(a)
```

The `insert()` function produces the whole tree while `insert_1()` and `construct_tree()` which do not return anything fail to do so. Is there a function to recursively construct the whole tree without using a `return` statement? Thank you very much.

Comment: Nothing is *ever passed by reference in python*, but often, people misuse the term "pass by reference".

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: With `root = treeNode(key)` you define `root` as a local variable. Forget this "pass by reference" and "pass by value"  from other languages and think of it as "pass by object".

Comment: @Matthias: I have revised the question.  root now is in the outer scope of function insert_1().  Why does the contruct_tree() function still not work?

Comment: In you own words, what is a "class variable"?

Comment: So you mean the `treeNode` **class** defined in your code (which is also an object because everything is an object in Python). I'll see if I can now figure out what you're asking…

Comment: @Hans I think what you are talking about is the name of your `class`(`treeNode`).  When people(me anyway) hear "class variable" they tend to think class attributes(as opposed to instance variables/attributes) which are not present in your example.

Comment: @martineau: It is an object type with specified properties. An instance of it is an object. The kind of object I just defined should be mutable. I could well be wrong. Does it help to answer my question?

Comment: @martineau: I am not really sure the title is appropriate. My objective is to make the insert_1() produce the whole binary tree. Maybe I am not making myself clear...

Comment: Classes *are* mutable, but that usually happens to instances of them. The scope of a class defined at the module level is the same as any other object defined there (like an integer, string, dictionary, etc). These objects can be accessed by name anywhere inside the module including within functions and methods of other classes. Anyway I agree that your question is unclear. How does the code in your question demonstrate that the output of the `insert_1()` function is not what is desired? Same for the `construct_tree()` function. Those should be implemented as methods of a `Tree` class.

Comment: Advice on asking questions here: Don't include unnecessary and unrelated third-party modules, like `numpy` when there are equivalents included in the standard library. Also provide the code that is the [mre] illustrating what you're asking. This will often eliminate the need for long Q & A sessions down here in the comment.

Comment: @martineau: I have revised my question. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: The update helps, I suppose but not so much with respect to the code. `insert()` is the only function that returns anything but that's ignored when it's called for each value in `a`. The other two functions don't return anything. I retracted my close vote, but still really don't understand what you're goal is. If `insert()` does what you want, why can't the other two just use it?

Comment: @martineau: Maybe I should just ask: how to recursively construct the tree without using any `return` statement? Does it clarify the question?

Comment: If you never assign to `root.rightChild` and `root.leftChild`, then you cannot possibly have constructed a tree with more than one node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `insert`, the base case of the recursion is when you're inserting into an empty subtree, represented by `None` being passed in as `root`. It works because you can create and return a new `treeNode` in that case, and the caller will do the right thing with the return value.

If you don't want to be using `return`, you need to push that base case up to the calling code, so it avoids making a call when a leaf node is going to be added:

```
def insert_no_return(root, key):
    assert(root != None) # we can't handle empty trees

    if root.key == key:
        return # no value here, just quit early
    elif root.key < key:
        if root.rightChild is None:                 # new base case
            root.rightChild = treeNode(key)
        else:
            insert_no_return(root.rightChild, key)  # regular recursive case, with no assignment
    elif root.key > key:
        if root.leftChild is None:                  # new base case for the other child
            root.leftChild = treeNode(key)
        else:
            insert_no_return(root.leftChild, key)   # no assignment here either
```

That's a bit more repetitive than the version with `return`, since the base case needs to be repeated for each possible new child, but the recursive lines are a bit shorter since they don't need to assign a value anywhere.

As the assert says at the top, you can't usefully call this on an empty tree (represented by `None`), since it has no way to change your existing reference to the `None` root. So `construct_tree` probably needs special logic to construct empty trees. Your current version of that function doesn't handle empty input at all (and redundantly tries to add the root value to the tree a second time):

```
def construct_tree(a):
    if len(a) == 0:     # special case to construct an empty tree
        return None

    it = iter(a)        # use an iterator to avoid redundant insertion of a[0]
    root = treeNode(next(it))
    for k in it:
        insert_no_return(root, k)
```

Comment: Nice. Why does your answer work while my `insert_1()` does not?

Comment: @Hans in yours, if `root.leftChild` or `root.rightChild` are `None` you're no longer mutating a `treeNode` instance. You're changing your name to point at a new object and not `None`.

Comment: Your `insert_1` never assigned to `root.leftChild` or `root.rightChild`, so it could never effectively build the tree. My `insert_no_return` has logic to assign only when needed. The `insert` code with `return` calls, *always* assigns to them when it recurses, even if most of the time (in a big tree) it will be reassigning the same nodes to the same places (which makes the code simpler, if perhaps less efficient).

Comment: @Blckknght: Could you please elaborate on "Your insert_1 never assigned to `root.leftChild` or `root.rightChild`"?   Does the following statement not do that?

if r is None:
     r = treeNode(key)

Comment: @Axe319: Does the following statement not make the final leaves `None`?  if r is None: r = treeNode(key)

Comment: No, that only binds the local variable (`r` in your commented example, `root` in the question). Python doesn't do pass-by-reference the way some other languages do, so rebinding an argument inside the function won't *ever* rebind anything outside the function.

Comment: I think I understand now. If one needs to access within a (nested) function an object outside, he needs to reach *inside* the said object by at least one 'layer' to manipulate the object; he cannot just manipulate the object as a whole. All the manipulations on the outside object in my `insert()` function and your `insert_no_return()` function are performed this way. That is why they succeeded. I have upvoted and accepted your answer.